# Python Assignment statement

Tags: python, bnf

I was going through the python assignment statement [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) .

Here python uses below [Backus–Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) for assignment statements.

```
assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (starred_expression | yield_expression)
target_list     ::=  target ("," target)* [","]
target          ::=  identifier
                     | "(" [target_list] ")"
                     | "[" [target_list] "]"
                     | attributeref
                     | subscription
                     | slicing
                     | "*" target
```

Where as [starred_expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-starred_expression) is in Backus-Naur Form is

```
starred_expression ::=  expression | (starred_item ",")* [starred_item]
starred_item       ::=  assignment_expression | "*" or_expr
```

and [yield_expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) in Backus-Naur Form is

```
yield_atom       ::=  "(" yield_expression ")"
yield_expression ::=  "yield" [expression_list | "from" expression]
```

After recursively going through all those related backnaur form of each sub expression given above. I am still scratching my head how does  simple assignment like `a=9` can fit into above back naur form. Specially how does the `9`, on the RHS of the given statement can fall into yield_expression or starred_exression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't it right here?

```
starred_expression ::=  expression | …
```

A `starred_expression` can be just an `expression`. It must be the case that `expression` encompasses numeric literals like `9`.

(Edited for clarity following comments.)

**UPDATE**

Here is the full line from `starred_expression` to `9`.

```
starred_expression     ::=  expression | (starred_item ",")* [starred_item]
expression             ::=  conditional_expression | lambda_expr
conditional_expression ::=  or_test ["if" or_test "else" expression]
or_test                ::=  and_test | or_test "or" and_test
and_test               ::=  not_test | and_test "and" not_test
not_test               ::=  comparison | "not" not_test
comparison             ::=  or_expr (comp_operator or_expr)*
or_expr                ::=  xor_expr | or_expr "|" xor_expr
xor_expr               ::=  and_expr | xor_expr "^" and_expr
and_expr               ::=  shift_expr | and_expr "&" shift_expr
shift_expr             ::=  a_expr | shift_expr ("<<" | ">>") a_expr
a_expr                 ::=  m_expr | a_expr "+" m_expr | a_expr "-" m_expr
m_expr                 ::=  u_expr | m_expr "*" u_expr | m_expr "@" m_expr |
                              m_expr "//" u_expr | m_expr "/" u_expr |
                              m_expr "%" u_expr
u_expr                 ::=  power | "-" u_expr | "+" u_expr | "~" u_expr
power                  ::=  (await_expr | primary) ["**" u_expr]
primary                ::=  atom | attributeref | subscription | slicing | call
atom                   ::=  identifier | literal | enclosure
literal                ::=  stringliteral | bytesliteral
                              | integer | floatnumber | imagnumber
integer                ::=  decinteger | bininteger | octinteger | hexinteger
decinteger             ::=  nonzerodigit (["_"] digit)* | "0"+ (["_"] "0")*
nonzerodigit           ::=  "1"..."9"
```

What makes it confusing is that for every element from `conditional_expression` down to `power`, the thing that makes it look like the "thing it is" is optional!

For instance, in `power`, the `**` operator is actually not even required. So we think of `2**16` as a `power`, but `2` also qualifies as a `power`. Similarly for `or_test`, an `or` keyword is not actually required.

It works like that all the way up. For every line, `9` satisfies the simplest version of the syntactic element with none of the optional parts included.

Comment: I have also provided bnf for starred_expression from the python docs which is not same as you.

Comment: user513951's point is that a `starred_expression` can just be an `expression`.  You don't provide the bnf for `expression` but undoubtedly it encompasses `9`.

Comment: I don't think it is the right  argument because every statement must follow grammar

Comment: @novice `9` is a [literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#literals), which is an [atom](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atoms), the most basic element of an `expression`. An [expression statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?#expression-statements) evaluates an [expression list](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists) which may be a single expression.   (continued in next comment)

Comment: The confusing part is that the only bnf given for `expression` is under [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-expression), and it only includes `expression ::=  conditional_expression | lambda_expr`, where both options refer back to expression. This seems like a documentation error in the that the full bnf for a `expression` isn't listed including literals, calls, etc - any link for `expression` goes to the conditional expressions block

Comment: @nigh_anxiety I think you are correct on every point.

Comment: Actually, the documentation isn't in error. It's just confusing that `2` qualifies as a `conditional_expression` because an `or_test` can just be an `and_test` instead of actually having an `or` in it, and an `and_test` can just be a `not_test` without having an `and` in it, and so on down the line.

Comment: @user513951  Yeah, after digging some more, it looks like a literal integer would satisfy the definition of an `or_expr`, which going up the chain satisifies the definition of `comparison` -> `not_test` -> `and_test` -> ``or_test` -> `conditional_expression` -> `expression`

Comment: Another route - `atoms` satisfy the definition of a [`primary`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#primaries), and a `primary` satisfies the [power operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) as in the definition `power ::=  (await_expr | primary) ["**" u_expr]`, the inclusion of the `** exponent` is completely optional.

Comment: `or_test                ::=  and_test | or_test "or" and_test` Does this mean that `or_test` is equivalent to `and_test` that means`x and y` is `or_test` expression.

Comment: @novice That's exactly right. The way it's set up facilitates [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) rules.

Comment: Hi @user513951, Thanks for all the help. Actually I am facing difficulty in following through entire BNF . If you don't mind , Would you please suggest me  steps so that I can check if the expression following BNF. I am kind of stucked in this.

Comment: @novice It seems like a very quick test of whether an expression is "following BNF" is to give the text to a python interpreter and see if throws a syntax error, no?

Comment: I meant I want to check it manually not through the compiler.